# Selecting multiple items in ListView

Tags: android

How to select multiple item in ListView in android.

Answer (score 44):

Actually you can ;) It's just a matter of user experience, right?

Try this, (1) for list control set

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);   
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

(2) define list item as

```
<CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:background="@drawable/txt_view_bg" />
```

This is same as `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` except 
`android:background="@drawable/txt_view_bg`

(3) And define drawable txt_view_bg.xml as

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected"
  android:state_checked="true" />  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/not_selected" />
```

Note:- The preferred way to handle multiple choice is to track choices your-self with on click item click, rather than depending on its state in list.

Comment: I assume that the item elements above are in a selector element, and that "selected" and "not_selected" are user supplied drawables (like an image).  Is there a way of using the platform's check boxes instead?

Comment: To use the platform's check boxes, remove the background attribute and ignore point (3). Although the boxes appear for me, unfortunately i am not able to actually check the box. I can do it only through the xml by using android:checked attribute to set a default value, but cannot change it at run time by touching it.

Answer (score 15):

**Step 1:** setAdapter to your listview.

```
 listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, GENRES));
```

**Step 2:** set choice mode for listview .The second line of below code represents which checkbox should be checked.

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setItemChecked(2, true);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



 private static  String[] GENRES = new String[] {
        "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
        "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
    };
```

**Step 3:** Checked views are returned in SparseBooleanArray, so you might use the below code to get key or values.The below sample are simply displayed selected names in a single String.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {

    SparseBooleanArray sp=getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

    String str="";
    for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
    {
        str+=GENRES[sp.keyAt(i)]+",";
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: if you unselect an item, it will continue to appear in the toast. So.. if you select 3 items, then unselect them and chose 1 other item, the string will contain all 4 items, even just 1 item is selected.I cannot explain why, because we always have a new String="". Does the `getCheckedItemPositions()` stores all the values that has been selected? but it would be strange. It would be nice to solve this , I have tried, but up to know I couldn't solve it. So, if somebody know, please share the solution.

Answer (score 4):

This example stores the values you have checked and displays them in a toast. And it updates when you uncheck items http://android-coding.blogspot.ro/2011/09/listview-with-multiple-choice.html

Answer (score 2):

To "update" the Toast message after unchecking some items, just put this line inside the for loop:

```
if (sp.valueAt(i))
```

so it results:

```
for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
{
    if (sp.valueAt(i))
        str+=names[sp.keyAt(i)]+",";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to have a contextual action bar with listview on multiselect, You can make listview as multiselect using the following code

```
listview.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

And now set multichoice listener for Listview ,You can see the complete implementation of multiselect listview at [Android multi select listview](http://codesfor.in/contextual-actionbar-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple,

```
listViewRequests.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    **AppCompatCheckedTextView checkBox = (AppCompatCheckedTextView) view;**
                    Log.i("CHECK",checkBox.isChecked()+""+checkBox.getText().toString());**

               }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

In listView you can use it by Adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChannels = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

and to get it :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "onItemClick(" + view + ","
                        + position + "," + id + ")");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the option in `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to check the logic of `ListActivity` according to what is needed could be the best way not to lose much time

[link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/listactivity/android-listactivity-example/)

[developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)