# How to get seleceted items from a listView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, cursor

I'm trying to find a way to add a checkBox to a ListView layout that can be used to allow the user to select items to be processed. The listview is populated using a cursor via a SimpleCursorAdapter.  Can anyone point in the direction on documentation describing how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the selected items in the listview in the getView method manually. At last you will get the selected items. use Arraylist or hashmap as per your need and comfort.

Hope it will help you.

Also refer these links:

[Android ListView with Checkboxes: How to capture checked items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557169/android-listview-with-checkboxes-how-to-capture-checked-items)

[Android ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

[Adding CheckBoxes to a Custom ListView in Android](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html)

[how to display all checked items from multiple choice listview](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/cvZbSri07KA)