# what is the alternative of the checkboxes in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a application in android

I want to add the categories of the food in my application .

now I am using the checkboxes .
so if the restaurant have that category , he will check the checkbox . 
but, this is looking vary tedious , there are 35 number of checkboxes .so it looks very bad.

I don't know any other widgets that can I use in this situation ...
suggest me if you get some idea. 
thanks...

Comment: You can try to use ListView with multiply choice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview

Comment: but still it seems tedious......

Comment: when we ask question in the Stack overflow , we add the Tags to it , Is Android have that type of Tags facility ?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the colour of the row in listview on clicking the row(instead of putting a check box) like this..

```
private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new 
         OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
                 v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);<--- add this colour in resources

             }
         };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is quite a subjective question, however, I will still give my suggestion.

Check out this open source [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/). Generally, it is a widget that imitate iPhone style spin-wheel menu/drop down list for Android.

You can create/manage a list of checkbox (maybe plus some text and image for each item) using the wheel widget, which IMO will gives your app a quite clean and fashion design and looks.

Hope this helps.