# putting button clickable in listview but its going to crashed the app

Tags: android

here my xml file to put in the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCityName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" 
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:textColor="@drawable/text_hover"


           android:paddingLeft="30dp"
           android:paddingTop="9dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
           android:background="@drawable/dest_hover"


            />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

this is my java code to handle the listview :

```
ListView lst;
Button chk;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.destination);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCities);
         lst.setFocusable(false);
            chk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.check);   
            chk.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("sukjhdskfskdgf", "ggogogogogogogogoggo");

                }
            });

    }
```

Error shown in the Log cat:

```
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emaven.triphills/com.emaven.triphills.Tab}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emaven.triphills/com.emaven.triphills.Destination}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emaven.triphills/com.emaven.triphills.Destination}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.emaven.triphills.Tab.onCreate(Tab.java:28)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     ... 11 more
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.emaven.triphills.Destination.onCreate(Destination.java:51)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-30 05:43:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     ... 21 more
```

Plz help me to resolve this problem. Thanking you

Comment: main part of the logcat is missing. can you repost it?

Comment: Post your layout where listview is and there is no need for 2 linearlayout have a signle leinearlayout or as isngle relative layout

Comment: Dude I am sure the button is not inside your destination.xml file. Thats why you are getting this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well the button which you are clicking is in another xml file which you are adding to the `Listview` but not in the `destination.xml` which is your main layout. Thats why you are getting this exception.

Looking at your code what I can suggest you the following,

Get the button inside you Listview adapter `getView()` like this,

```
View vi = convertView;

Button  chk=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.check);  
 chk.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("sukjhdskfskdgf", "ggogogogogogogogoggo");

                }
            });
```

Comment: yes bro....but i am using the : SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Destination.this, hslist, R.layout.destnationlist, from, to); this is my destinationlist xxl file which i mentioned above then how can i got the solution

Comment: @RavindMaurya you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Your current layout in `destination.xml` and you have button in different xml. you can't initialize like that

Comment: @RavindMaurya: as Raghunandan said, you can't initialize the button like that way.Asuming that the button is inside your listview, I edited my post.see it.

Comment: @Raghunandan so how can i called that button in the list

Comment: @RavindMaurya shows us your adapter code. try the above in your adapter `getView`

Comment: @user2012 i did not understand by convertview ; will you elaborate how to implement it.

Comment: @RavindMaurya: Post your adapter code otherwise we can't suggest you anything.

Comment: @RavindMaurya too much to post. get to know adapters from the docs. If you don't know how to implement a custom adapter then read some tuttorials or search on stackoverflow.

Comment: @user2012
         String[] from  = {"city_name"};
         
         // Id's of views in listview_layout
         int[] to={R.id.tvCityName};
         
            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
         
               SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Destination.this, hslist, R.layout.destnationlist, from, to);
        
         lst.setAdapter(adapter);

          lst.setOnItemClickListener(Destination.this);

Comment: @RavindMaurya: post your SimpleAdapter class.

Comment: @user2012 i am using inbuild simple adapter class not making the custom adaper....

Comment: @RavindMaurya: I afraid you can't achieve that without using custom Adapter.Go for custom adapter, its damn easy and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the activity class inside the application tag in manifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.emaven.triphills.Destination"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that but you're doing it totally wrong. You should take your time and read through a [good list view tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

The basic idea behind ListView is to have a list that is populated with items from dataset. To achieve this you define an Activity layout with a ListView on it. You create a layout to display an individual item (I suspect this is the layout you included).
To populate the list view, you have to define an adapter that takes the dataset, and generates the views for individual items.

Android platform offers default list adapters for string arrays with default item views, but if you want to have a button on each item, you have to create your own layout and adapter.

By the way if you have only a single action - Check - associated with each item, you can use a simple itemclicklistener and loose the button. That way you can use a default list adapter.

If check results in some kind of selection state, [take a look at multi select mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview)