# Underline selected listview items

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to the list items in listview to be underlined when selected? I use custom layout (textview) for list item

This is what i want to achieve:
[image]

```
 myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition
                    (position);
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));

            s.append(title);
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            TextView shopName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_version);
            SpannableString content = new SpannableString(shopName.getText());
            content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
            shopName.setText(content);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to underline a text in a TextView, you could use the html tags `<u> </u>` as just changing the text of the selected textView like this for example:

```
String underlined = "<u>" + textView.getText() + "</u>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(underlined));
```

Or do it "like a boss" :D :

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
textView.setText(content);
```

Or another way:

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()|Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

In all cases textView is your `TextView`. I think that the second approach could be better than the other two.

Hopefully this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for your response :j i'll try it

Comment: the underline works only in the first row and i want it to be multiselect, please help :)

Comment: Did you implement the multiselection to your listView? If not, you could do it this way for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview