# How to add multiple items in Listview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter

I'm working on an Android application of booking medicine offline. I have used ListView for Cart, but whenever I add a new item in cart, my previous item get replaced.

```
L1 = imageacidity 
L2 = imagecough

 if(msg.toString().equals("L1")) {

       adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.list, imageacidity);
       ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }
   if(msg.toString().equals("L2"))
   {

       adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.list, imagecough);
       ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Here I have 5 elements in `imageacidity` and `Imagecough` Array. Whenever I select 1 item, it gets added in cart, but when I try to select another item it get replaced with new one.

Comment: If you mean you can't select more but only one item in your ListView, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview

Comment: @nvi9. Thank you so much for your response . Exactly not more then one item.

Comment: Every time you make a new Adapter, and do `dataList.setAdapter(adapter);` you completely remove the old data. Is that the problem you are having?

Comment: I had the same understanding cricket_007 did. @nvi9, you should post your  comment as an answer so we can upvote it and it can be accepted. :)

Comment: @cricket_007  means I must remove that line. Let me try. Thank you so much  and let you know

Comment: @RahulChhuttani Well, don't just remove it. Then there will be no data added to the adapter at all.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah Exactly Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing of the data being removed is happening because making a `new ContactImageAdapter` and calling `setAdapter`, which will completely remove the data that was already in the ListView.

If you want to properly implement the code in the question, you need something like this.

```
String msg = ""; // TODO: get this String value
ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

// TODO: Define a single List to store the data and use that in *one* adapter
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.list, contacts);
dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

// TODO: Replace this with the object to add to the adapter
Contact contact = null;

if(msg.equals("L1")) {
    // TODO: Use whatever values you want for "L1"
    int img = R.drawable.bati_acidity_1;
    String name = "Amlapitta";
    String price = "price 170";
    contact = new Contact(img, name, price); 
}
else if(msg.equals("L2")) {
    // TODO: Use whatever values you want for "L2"
    int img = R.drawable.bati_acidity_2;
    String name = "Amlapitta2";
    String price = "price 270";
    contact = new Contact(img, name, price); 
}
if (contact != null) {
    contacts.add(contact); 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Another problem is that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` without actually changing the datasets of `imageacidity` or `imagecough`.

Comment: Showing Error in m=new Medicine("L1");

Comment: @RahulChhuttani Well, yeah. This is only an example, not runnable code.

Comment: Sorry Sir. I'm new to android Development.  Though I Tried.

Comment: That's fine. I will leave my answer because StackOverflow is designed to help everyone, not only the person asking the question.

Comment: Agreed. Can you please tell me replacement of L1 with actual code I mean what I have to pass on that.

Comment: imageacidity.add(new Contact(R.drawable.bati_acidity_1, "Amlapitta","price 270"));
I have 5 items in each Array.this is 1 item of array. So what should i write now ?

Comment: ContactImageAdapter adapter;

Comment: ArrayList<Contact> imageacidity = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Sir might be this will help you completely now

Comment: Image will help you. Thank you once again @cricket_007

Comment: It would have helped more if you actually included that code into your question. Regardless, it is still not clear why you have so many separate lists, but are trying to use only one ListView.

Comment: Sorry for Ambiguities. If i would add that code people might ignore my question due to Big code. Listview is Cart i which i want to add product. Different Array hai Different product of idian medicine. I have implemented as i click on 1 product I am able to see in cart but when ever i click to buy another my previous get replaced. dis is the Actual problem. I only need to add multiple items in Listview

Comment: If you don't post a [mcve], though, you will get vague, incomplete, answers with people guessing at what you want. If you want multiple items in a ListView, then use one adapter, one ArrayList, and just add data to that list.

Comment: As per your suggestion I'm updating my code and Sorry might be I was not cleared with my problem and shared less info. Thank you sir for your Strong Support.  @cricket_007

Answer (score 5):

You have to Add the element inside your adapter.
I will post a custom Adapter and show you how to add elements properly.

Adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<String> itens;
    private Context mContext;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public YourAdapter(Context context, List<String> itens){
        this.itens = itens;
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itens.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return itens.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        String msg = itens.get(position);

        TextView tx = vi.findViewById(R.id.your_id);

        tx.setText(msg);

        return vi;
    }

    public void addItem(String item){
        itens.add(item);
    }

    public void addItens(List<String> itens){
        this.itens.addAll(itens);
    }
}
```

ListView:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,yourListOfItens);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

You can set initial data on constructor of adapter, or use methods addItem and addAll on a click button for example.

Comment: `getItem` shouldn't return null. Plus, you could just use `ArrayAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm (logic) on the **InputListAdapter** checking and verifying if there is a MedicineVO (**Value Object Pattern**) item on old list before the calling `notyChange(..)` method. In addition, you can wrapping the logic in other class such as `MedicineLogic` to improve the adapter readability.

See the sample code below:

```
    public class MedicineInputListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MedicineVo> {
    public static final int[]   COLORS  = new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE };

    private Context mContext;
    private List<MedicineVo> medicineVos;
    private MedicineVo medicineVoActual;


    public BasePreOSPreventivaCorretivaInputListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MedicineVo> medicineVos) {
        super(context, resource, medicineVos);

        this.medicineVoActual = new MedicineVo();
        this.medicineVos = new ArrayList<MedicineVo>();
        this.medicineVos.addAll(medicineVos);

        this.mContext = context;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {        
        TextView mMedicineTextView;
        //------------------------------------------------------
        // others Android view components 
        //------------------------------------------------------

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            //------------------------------------------------------
            // mapper from xml to view and add itens to holder
            //------------------------------------------------------





            //------------------------------------------------------
            // add event action to the mMedicineTextView
            //------------------------------------------------------
            viewHolder.mMedicineTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                    MedicineVo medicineVo = (MedicineVo) textView.getTag();

                    boolean selected = medicineVo.getSelected();
                    if (selected) {
                        /*do it*/
                    }

                    refreshPreOSMaterialWhenUpdate(preOSMaterialVo);

                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------
        // get item and adjust color
        //------------------------------------------------------
        MedicineVo item = getItem(position);

        /*do it*/

        return convertView;
    }



    public void refreshMedicineListWhenUpdate(MedicineVo medicineVo){
        List<MedicineVo> newMedicineVos = new ArrayList<MedicineVo>();

        for (MedicineVo medicineVoOnList : medicineVos) {
            if( StringUtils.isNull(medicineVoOnList.getId()) )
                continue;

            if( MedicineLogic.existsOnList(medicineVos, medicineVoOnList) )
                continue;

            /* others checks if necessary */    

            newMedicineVos.add(medicineVoOnList);


        }
        medicineVos.addAll(newMedicineVos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @EAA but I'm new though feeling difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't select more but only one item of your `ListView`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview) might help.
*As others have commented on the question, changing the adapter of a `ListView` can clear the selection too, but as I supposed the code you've posted is inside `onCreate` (or other kind of initialization) so setting the adapter there won't affect the selection (since there can't be selection without items... :) )*

Comment: Thank you @nvi9. I'm new but Trying my level best to understand the code. I tried listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);  but showing error. Though I'm unable to use such method.